# Update observableArray only on event

Tags: knockout.js

### [Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UyEVK/1/)

---

*Note: I'm currently learning with KnockoutJS so any guidance on best practices, or corrections on whether I'm doing things right are always appreciated!*

I am working on a test project trying to get to grips with the brilliant KnockoutJS and I'm now at a point where I need to think about deferring the update of my `observableArray`. I have a view model of items (which I'm retrieving via an AJAX call), and a table that lists them. When I click on an item, a modal pops up populated with the details and allows me to edit them. Let's just call them *items* for now, here's the definition.

```
var itemViewModel = function (id, name) {
    this.Id = ko.observable(id);
    this.Name = ko.observable(name);
};
```

When I click on the item, I set a `selectedItemId` and then loop through my items looking for the correct one, when found I set it to `selectedItem` and show the modal.

```
var targetItem = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.items(), function (current) {
    return current.Id() === self.selectedItemId();
});
self.selectedItem(targetItem);
```

All working perfectly so far, but my `observableArray` is getting updated irrespective of whether I click **Close** or **Save** in the modal. Now, I'm aware this is correct behavior, but my question is: how do I update my `observableArray` ONLY when I click **Save**?

Here's how I *think* I should be doing it (but I'm not entirely sure whether I'm correct).

I should have a non-observable version of `itemViewModel` (still extracted from the `items` collection as before, but without the observables) and then call some event when I click **Save** on the modal that replaces the item in the `observableArray` like so:

```
self.items.replace(oldItem, newItem);
```

While the above does seem logical, I'm not sure if it makes full use of KnockoutJS or not. The main thing that irks me about the above, is having to have the non-observable version of `itemViewModel`, can I not just unsubscribe or dispose the tracking?

Comment: You should start with this article: http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/01/simple-editor-pattern-knockout-js.html and also its "first part" http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html

Comment: @nemesv That's a really good article, thanks for this. Reading through it now.

Comment: @nemesv Managed to do this with those articles, thanks again!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Solution jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UyEVK/3/)

---

A huge thanks to the article provided by **nemesv**, which gave me all I need to do exactly what I wanted to do!  For anyone else stumbling on this with the same question, here's what I did.

I used the `protectedObservable` that was defined in [this article](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html) and followed his example of committing and rolling back changes. So I defined my `itemViewModel` like this:

```
var itemViewModel = function (id, name) {
    this.Id = ko.protectedObservable(id);
    this.Name = ko.protectedObservable(name);
    this.commit = function () {
        this.Id.commit();
        this.Name.commit();
    };
    this.rollback = function() {
        this.Id.reset();
        this.Name.reset();
    };
};
```

Then applied the same two `commit` and `rollback` methods to my overall view model (which just invoke the `$parent.commit` and `$parent.rollback` methods on the event of clicking **Save** like this:

```
var viewModel = function (items) {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray(items);
    self.selectedItemId = ko.observable();
    self.selectedItem = ko.observable();
    self.selectItem = function () {
        var targetItem = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.items(), function (current) {
            return current.Id() === self.selectedItemId();
        });
        self.selectedItem(targetItem);
        $('#edit-item-modal').dialog('open');
    };
    self.commit = function () {
        self.selectedItem().commit();
        $('#edit-item-modal').dialog('close');
    };
    self.rollback = function () {
        self.selectedItem().rollback();
        $('#edit-item-modal').dialog('close');
    };
};
```

I really like this solution, so thanks again to **nemesv** for the information!